# KeyboardAvoidingView doesn't work inside tab navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using the built-in KeyboardAvoidingView in react native and when I use the code below in a screen where you can't see the tabs (like in a modal) it works perfectly fine and the keyboard doesn't cover any content whatsoever, but when I use the exact same code but in a screen that is used in tab navigation the keyboard covers some content, it's like the KeyboardAvoidingView doesn't take into consideration the height of the bottom tabs

Here's my code:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex: 1}} behavior="padding">
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
        {content}
    </ScrollView>
    <TextInput 
        style={{height: 50, width: "100%", backgroundColor: "red"}}
        placeholder="Test input"
    />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: behavior="height" , try this

Comment: @GauravRoy Same result.. also tried setting it to "position" and in "position" it hides the TextInput below the tabs...

Comment: did you got the solution to solve this issue?